# How to print all the substrings from a file using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have the text file like this

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.6.106
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
                                   10.0.0.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.6.107
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
                                   10.0.0.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.6.108
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
                                   10.0.0.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.6.109
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
                                   10.0.0.1
```

I want to print all the IPv4 Addresses from this file using python script.
Currently I am able to print only first IPv4 (10.0.6.106) address only with the below python script.

**ip =  open("ip.txt").read().split("IPv4 ")[1].split(":")[1].split("\n")[0].strip()
print ip**

please help me to print all the IPv4 adresses.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
with open('ip.txt') as ip:
    for line in ip:
        if line.startswith('IPv4 Address'):
            line = line.split(':')
            print line[1].strip()
```

Comment: But how to read if IPv4 Address does not found at line starting.Like Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.6.107

Comment: This code reads data you provided, do you have an additional example?

Comment: Thanks zipa for the reply.Please find the below quesytion for the exact requirement

Answer (score 0):

I have text file like this

```
[   59.095037] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 Frame Name: Tx2Tx
[   59.102857] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #23# 0x0119# 001113
[   59.102971] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #23# 0x0306# 005252
[   59.103079] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #23# 0x0110# 055222
[   59.103229] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #23# 0x0074# 006433
[   59.103341] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #23# 0x0071# 023523

[   59.095037] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 Frame Name: Rx2Tx
[   59.102857] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #22# 0x0120# 004322
[   59.102971] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #22# 0x0303# 005325
[   59.103079] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #22# 0x0111# 009940
[   59.103229] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #22# 0x0075# 007544
[   59.103341] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #22# 0x0079# 001221

[   59.095037] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 Frame Name: Rx2Bsave
[   59.102857] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #24# 0x0125# 001123
[   59.102971] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #24# 0x0309# 007704
[   59.103079] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #24# 0x0133# 002323
[   59.103229] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #24# 0x0085# 002433
[   59.103341] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #24# 0x0032# 000875

[   59.095037] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 Frame Name: Bsave2Tx
[   59.102857] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #25# 0x0122# 000232
[   59.102971] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #25# 0x0311# 001223
[   59.103079] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #25# 0x0113# 004422
[   59.103229] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #25# 0x0333# 004343
[   59.103341] TRACE0 LOG  task: pid:0 errid:0 #25# 0x0323# 000212
```

I need to sort out the data based on frame name.
In the above I have 4 frame names TX2TX,Rx2Tx,Rx2Bsave,Bsave2Tx.
I need to identify those frame names and extact its data and create excel sheet and write into corresponding sheets.

Below is the code Which wrote for this purpose.
I am able to create the excel sheet but I am unable to write into its individual sheets.

```
 import xlwt

 wbk = xlwt.Workbook()    

 row = 4 # row counter
col = 0
sheet_number = 0

f = open('Log1.txt')

 for line in f:
    if 'Frame Name' in line:
         sheet_number += 1
         sheetname = line.split(':')[-1]

        sheet = wbk.add_sheet(sheetname)
        wbk.active_sheet = 0

      L = line.split('#')
        for i,c in enumerate(L):        
       sheet.write(row,i,c)
     row += 1

 wbk.save('example.xls')
```